# would like vs simple present tense

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> 1) After we go for a run, I would like some tea.

---

> 2) After we go for a run, I  like some tea

---

What is the difference between the meanings of these two sentences?

Comment: There's no difference since the sentences are identical. I guess your second sentence should be `After we go for a run, I want some tea`, right?

Comment: sorry for wrong question. Now I have edited it. "I would like some tea" vs "I like some tea"